# Why am I getting this error when running a Python script with the MySQL Connector?

Tags: python, mysql, database

So I am currently working on a project which involves creating a Python application to interact with a MySQL database.

With this Python app, i was able to successfully insert rows into a table known as student, but when inserting a row into the enrollment table, it will not work. I will attach all information which may be useful below. Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Python Code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

def printEmptySpace():
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")

try:
  #connection opened at start of program execution
  mysql_connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="Caden9036", database="caden_inf2070_project")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Incorrect Username and/or Password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Specified schema does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  print("DB and Schema connections were successful")

menu = "Choose An Option\n\n1 - Add\n2 - Remove\n3 - Update\n\nOption: "
option = input(menu)

while option != "1" and option != "2" and option != "3":
    option = input(menu)

printEmptySpace()

if option == "1":
    errors = 0
   
    studentname = input("Student name (First & Last): ").title()
    period = int(input("Period Id: (1 - P1, 2 - HS2, 3 - HS4, 4 - HS6) "))
    courseid = int(input("Course Id: "))
    moduleid = int(input("Module Id: "))

    printEmptySpace()

    if len(studentname.split(" ")) != 2:
      print("Error: Student name must consist of a first and a last name.")
      errors += 1

    if period <= 0 or period >= 5:
      print("Error: Period can only be a number between one and four.")
      errors += 1

    if courseid <= 0 or courseid >= 6:
      print("Error: Course ID can only be a number between one and five.")
      errors += 1

    validmodules = [
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [6,7,8,9,10],
      [11,12,13,14,15],
      [16,17,18,19,20],
      [21,22,23,24,25]
    ]

    isvalid = False
    if courseid >= 1 or courseid <= 5:
      for i,v in enumerate(validmodules[courseid-1]):
        if v == moduleid:
          isvalid = True

      if isvalid == False:
        print("Error: The selected module is not a member of the selected course.")
        errors += 1

    if errors >= 1:
      print("Please review the provided errors, and re-run the program.")
    else:
      print("No errors found.")
      print("Enrolling student...")

      mysql_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
      mysql_query = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(student_id), 0) + 1 FROM student"
      mysql_cursor.execute(mysql_query)
      next_student_id = mysql_cursor.fetchone()[0]

      mysql_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
      mysql_query = "INSERT INTO student (student_id, student_name, fk_period_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
      mysql_cursor.execute(mysql_query, (next_student_id, studentname, period))
      mysql_connection.commit()
      mysql_cursor.close()

      print("One record added to the student table.")

      mysql_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
      mysql_query = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(primary_id), 0) + 1 FROM enrollment"
      mysql_cursor.execute(mysql_query)
      next_primary_id = mysql_cursor.fetchone()[0]
      mysql_connection.commit()

      mysql_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
      mysql_query = "INSERT INTO enrollment (primary_id, fk_student_id, fk_course_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
      mysql_cursor.execute(mysql_query, (next_primary_id, next_student_id, courseid))
      mysql_connection.commit()
      mysql_cursor.close()


      print("One record added to enrollment.")

      print("Student has been successfully enrolled.")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-8365893-1662656297.95/build/root/Library/Python/3.9/install.tmp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 565, in cmd_query
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`caden_inf2070_project`.`enrollment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_course_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_student_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cadenjohnson/Desktop/Coding/caden_inf2070_project.py", line 95, in <module>
    mysql_cursor.execute(mysql_query, (next_primary_id, next_student_id, courseid))
  File "/Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-8365893-1662656297.95/build/root/Library/Python/3.9/install.tmp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 279, in execute
  File "/Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-8365893-1662656297.95/build/root/Library/Python/3.9/install.tmp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 573, in cmd_query
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`caden_inf2070_project`.`enrollment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_course_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_student_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Let me know if there is another piece of information that would be helpful in solving this.

I have tried to drop and re-add these foriegn keys, but I am not sure if they are correct or not. In that error it appears that some of them are referencing the wrong tables, but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi @Caden, It looks like you are trying to insert a row into the table enrollment without having a row with provided course_id as primary in the table course.

Assure the course_id is valid in the course table and it will work.

Comment: I can confirm that the course table has a primary key of "course_id". This program is still not working.

Comment: Yes, but do you have a row in the course table with the provided course_id primary key?

Comment: The course table has Ids ranging from 1 to 5, which is what the program requires. So yes, I believe so. When I execute the program, I supply a course_id of 1 to 5.

Comment: I tried printing the courseid variable, and it resulted in 5, which is what i entered. 5 is also a value in the course table. With this in mind, I am not sure if the issue that you stated is the problem that I am having here.